# Boundary conditions for differential forms

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, differential-forms, manifolds-with-boundary, gauge-theory

I am trying to understand differential forms on manifolds with boundaries, and I am a bit confused with the boundary conditions.

For the following, let $(M,g_M)$ be a smooth Riemannian manifold with boundary $\partial M$, define $\iota:\partial M\hookrightarrow M$ the inclusion of the boundary, and $\star$ is the Hodge-star with respect to $g_M$.

In [1] the authors define the space of $p$-forms satisfying Dirichlet $(\Omega^p_{\text{D}}(M))$ and Neumann $(\Omega^p_{\text{N}}(M))$ boundary conditions. Their definition, towards the end of page 3, is equivalent to
\begin{align}
\Omega^p_{\text{D}}(M) &:= \Big\lbrace\omega\in\Omega^p(M)\ \Big\vert\ \iota^*\omega = 0\Big\rbrace \\
\Omega^p_{\text{N}}(M) &:= \Big\lbrace\omega\in\Omega^p(M)\ \Big\vert\ \iota^*\star\omega = 0\Big\rbrace .\end{align}

Verbosely, this defines *Dirichlet $p$-forms*, as $p$-forms that vanish upon eating vectors that are *tangent* to $\partial M$, and *Neumann $p$-forms* as $p$-forms that vanish upon eating vectors *normal* to $\partial M$.

Had I not seen that definition I would have defined Dirichlet $p$-forms in the same way, but the Neumann ones I would define by demanding that their derivative along the normal directions to $\partial M$ vanishes, in the same fashion as one does for functions. This translates to demanding that
$$\iota^*\star\mathrm{d}\omega = 0.$$

My question is, *is my definition of Neumann $p$-forms the same as [1]'s*? I would expect not, as having vanishing $\star\mathrm{d}\omega$ is clearly less restrictive than having vanishing $\star\omega$. But then, if not, *why is their definition justified as Neumann boundary conditions*? I.e. *how does it generalize the usual Neumann boundary conditions for functions in a natural way*, and *why is my naive definition wrong*?

Moreover, a space that is important is the space
$$\Omega^p_{\text{important}}(M) := \Big\lbrace\omega\in\Omega^p(M)\ \Big\vert\ \iota^*\mathrm{d}\omega = 0\Big\rbrace.$$
This space arises naturally in gauge theories as the space of gauge transformations that vanish on the boundary. *How is this space related to $\Omega^p_{\text{D}}(M)$ or $\Omega^p_{\text{N}}(M)$*? (apart from the obvious $\Omega^p_{\text{D}}(M)\subset\Omega^p_{\text{important}}(M)$)

---

References: [1] Sylvain Cappell, Dennis DeTurck, Herman Gluck, Edward Y. Miller, *Cohomology of Harmonic Forms on Riemannian Manifolds With Boundary*,
https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0508372

Answer (score 1):

This isn’t entirely an answer, rather a bit of intuition.  The gist of it is that “Dirichlet” and “Neumann” collectively refer to boundary conditions which give rise to a well-posed elliptic system.  In the case of the Hodge Decomposition Theorem, the relevant elliptic system is
$$ \Omega^0 \overset{d}{\longrightarrow} \Omega^1 \overset{d}{\longrightarrow} \Omega^2 \overset{d}{\longrightarrow} \dotsm $$
The boundary condition arises by doing integration by parts:
$$ \langle d\alpha, \beta \rangle = \int_M d\alpha \wedge \star\beta = \pm \int_M \alpha \wedge d\star\beta + \int_{\partial M} \alpha \wedge \star\beta . $$
($\pm$ because I am too lazy to think about the sign.)
The key point here is that the boundary term vanishes if either $\iota^\ast\alpha=0$ or $\iota^\ast\star\beta=0$, giving the two different boundary conditions.
They are called “Dirichlet” and “Neumann” only because the first condition says something only about how $\alpha$ acts on tangential vectors, while the latter condition includes information about the normal component of $\beta$.

I am not sure how to answer your second question except to point at the Hodge Decomposition Theorem in your reference.
I will point out that you have the wrong inclusion: Since $\iota^\ast d\omega = d\iota^\ast\omega$, we see that $\iota^\ast\omega=0$ implies $d\iota^\ast\omega=0$.

Comment: Thanks, +1. I'll attempt to rephrase the gist of your answer to see if I understood. You're saying that in order to arrive at the Hodge decomposition we need self-adjointness of the Laplacian, which in turn requires ellipticity of de Rham complex, in the case with boundaries. That can only happen if $\delta$ is the $L^2$-adjoint of $\mathrm{d}$, which leads to requiring that the boundary terms vanish. And then the rest of your answer follows. Is that right? (1/2)

Comment: (2/2) But why is that the relevant inner-product to look at? If I play the same game applied to $\left\langle\mathrm{d}a,\mathrm{d}a\right\rangle$, I get that $\delta$ is adjoint to $\mathrm{d}$ if $\iota^*a=0$ or if $\iota^*\star\mathrm{d}a=0$, giving the BCs I would naively write. 

Also, of course I have the wrong inclusion, thanks for spotting that, corrected now.

Comment: The orthogonal decomposition on page 4 of your linked reference is with respect to the usual $L^2$-inner product; i.e. what I am using.  It easily follows from the formula I wrote that their decomposition is in fact orthogonal.  The reason to use this inner product is just that the formal adjoint of $d$ is $\delta$, rather than something else.  Also, note that in your reference, the relevant space is the space of closed and coclosed forms, not of harmonic forms; this is why they are not looking at boundary conditions associated to the Hodge Laplacian.

Comment: Sure, that's clear, I wasn't proposing to use a different inner-product. I just observed that if you apply this to $\left<\mathrm{d}a,\mathrm{d}a\right>$ you get my proposed Dirichlet and Neumann BCs, rather than theirs